# How to change Submit button text from a view in crispy-forms?

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

In my forms.py I have the following:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(
    Fieldset(
        None,
        'name'
    ),
    FormActions(
        Submit('submit', 'Add Thing', css_class='btn-primary')
    )
)
```

But I am using the same view to add and edit the item. So I want to change the button text (Add Thing above) based on some condition in my views.py. How can I do that?

Comment: I have not used crispy-forms before. However, django is still python. So can't you define a function that renders different classes (if that is what you are looking for) based on conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to pass an argument to the form class that determines the Submit button text.

A dummy example:

view

```
...
form = MyFormClass(is_add=True)
...
```

form class

```
class MyFormClass(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.is_add = kwargs.pop("is_add", False)
        super(MyFormClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def helper(self):
        helper = FormHelper()
        helper.layout = Layout(
            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', 'Add Thing' if self.is_add else 'Edit thing', css_class='btn-primary')
            )
        )
        return helper
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple improvement over @kviktor's answer. Prepare your form to accept an additional argument `submit_label` and use it to name your button.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        submit_label = kwargs.pop("submit_label", "Submit")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset(
                None,
                'name'
            ),
            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', submit_label, css_class='btn-primary')
            )
        )
```

Override the `get_form` method of your view to instantiate the form yourself passing the value of `submit_label` depending on your conditions.

```
class MyView(generic.FormView):
    def get_form(self):
        form = MyForm(**super().get_form_kwargs(), submit_label="Add Thing")
        return form
```

Comment: Is the answer to change a single label actually over 10 lines?

Comment: Actually I think crispy form was not developed keeping in mind such scenario where you have to set the label from view, that's why you have to write so much.